# Cannot set a style for clicked features in vector layer

Tags: openlayers-3

So in my Openlayers 3 I set a default style , that renders features the first time the layer loads

```
function styleFunction(feature, resolution) {
    var color = feature.get('color');
    var name = feature.get('name');

    var fill = new ol.style.Fill({
        color: color
    });

    var stroke = new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: "black",
        lineCap: "butt",
        lineJoin: "bevel",
        width:1         
    });

    var text= new ol.style.Text({
        font: '20px Verdana',
        text: name,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: [64, 64, 64, 0.5]
        })
    })

    var cStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        fill: fill,
        stroke: stroke,
        text: text
    });

    return [cStyle];
}
```

When a feature is clicked I want that feature to change its style and the rest to keep the default style above.

This is my attempt to do this

```
 //add simple click interaction to the map
 var select = new ol.interaction.Select();
 map.addInteraction(select);

//for every clicked feature
 select.on('select', function(e) {
       var name = e.selected[0].get('name');

       //set the clicked style
        var fillClick= new ol.style.Fill({
            color: "black"
         });

        var strokeClick = new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: "white",
            lineCap: "butt",
            lineJoin: "bevel",
            width:3         
        });

        var textClick= new ol.style.Text({
                font: '10px Verdana',
                text: name,
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: [64, 64, 64, 1]
                })
            })

        var styleClick = new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: strokeClick,
            fill : fillClick,
            text : textClick
        });



    //set all to default
    for (i in e.selected){
        e.selected[i].setStyle(styleFunction);  
    }

    //reset the first selected to the clicked style
    e.selected[0].setStyle(styleClick);
```

I dont get any errors on the console, but this wont work. The clicked feature wont return to the default style when I click another one. All the clicked features keep the `styleClick`.

So, how do I fix this and also, is there a simpler way to do this? I think its a lot of code for this kind of functionality

Thanks

**EDIT**

I replaced

```
    for (i in e.selected){
        e.selected[i].setStyle(styleFunction);  
    }
```

with

```
    var allfe = sourceVector.getFeatures(); 

    for (i in allfe){
        allfe[i].setStyle(styleFunction);   
    }
```

So now all the features will get the style defined in the `styleFunction` function.

This does not work. I get `Uncaught TypeError: feature.get is not a function` referring to the first line of the function, `var color = feature.get('color');` this one.

I cannot just set a style, I need it to be a function so I can check the geomerty type in the future.

So my two problems,

I dont know how to debug and fix this error

If I have like 500 features, redrawing all of them for every click, will slow the rendering. Is there another solution to this?

Thanks

Comment: Hey, @slevin, how does this end up?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Layer and feature style functions are different**

When using OpenLayers 3 style functions, you have to note the difference between an [`ol.FeatureStyleFunction`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/apidoc/ol.html#.FeatureStyleFunction) and a [`ol.style.StyleFunction`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/apidoc/ol.style.html#.StyleFunction). They are very similar, since they both should return an array of `ol.Style`s based on a feature and a resolution. They are, however, not provided with that information in the same way.

When providing a style function to a feature, using it's `setStyle` method, the function should be an `ol.FeatureStyleFunction`. An `ol.FeatureStyleFunction` is called with `this` referencing the feature, and with the `resolution` as the only argument.

When providing a style function to a layer, it should be an `ol.style.StyleFunction`. They are called with two arguments, the `feature` and the `resolution`.

This is the cause of your error. You are using an `ol.style.StyleFunction` as a feature style. Later, when your style function is called, the first argument is the resolution and not the feature that you are expecting.

**Solution 1: setStyle(null)**

This solution has already been proposed in @jonatas-walker's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33322722/cannot-set-a-style-for-clicked-features-in-vector-layer/33399885#33399885). It works by setting a style on your selected features and removing the style from the unselected ones (instead of setting your style function to the unselected features).

OpenLayers will use the feature's style if it has one, and otherwise use the layer's style. So re-setting the unselected features' style to null will make them use the layer's style function again.

**Solution 2: use the `style` option of your select interaction**
[`ol.interaction.Select`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/apidoc/ol.interaction.Select.html) accepts a style option (an `ol.style.StyleFunction`), which is used to style the selected features.

Pros: Having one style function for the layer (normal view) and a style function for the select interaction makes the code more readable than mixing feature and layer styles. Also, you don't have to keep track of the events or modify the features.

It could be done similar to this:

```
var selectedStyleFunction = function(feature, resolution) {
    return [new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: "white",
            lineCap: "butt",
            lineJoin: "bevel",
            width:3         
        }),
        fill : new ol.style.Fill({
            color: "black"
        }),
        text : new ol.style.Text({
            font: '10px Verdana',
            text: feature.get('name'),
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: [64, 64, 64, 1]
            })
        })
    })];
};
var select = new ol.interaction.Select({
    style: selectedStyleFunction
});
map.addInteraction(select);
```

Comment: Very well explained answer. Let's divide the reward?

Comment: @JonatasWalker Thanks. Is it possible to split bounties?

Comment: Just kidding. I don't think so.

Comment: @AlvinLindstam So, to create a `ol.FeatureStyleFunction` I have to do `function styleFunction3(resolution) {
 var color = this.p_color; //set fill, stroke etc....`  . But `var color = this.color;` and also `var color = this.get('color');` throw an error. So how I get data from the feature to be styled? Thanks

Comment: @slevin: Yes, in an `ol.FeatureStyleFunction` `this` will reference the feature. If you get those errors you are probably setting that `ol.FeatureStyleFunction` on a layer/interaction instead of on a feature. Se Jonatas' answer for a working example of using `this` to get the feature in an `ol.FeatureStyleFunction`.

Comment: @AlvinLindstam Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: @AlvinLindstam @JonatasWalker There is a nice workaround proposed on ol3's gitHub for those who would like to use the same styleFunction for both features and layers. Simply add a check on `feature` to see if it is on instance of `ol.Feature`, otherwise set it to `this`. Original post is here [link](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/3502)

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE** - [fiddle styling with `ol.interaction.Select`](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/e4reqeqj/)

How about - http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/zz6d4z7d/

```
var select = new ol.interaction.Select();
map.addInteraction(select);

var styleClick = function() {
    // `this` is ol.Feature
    return [
        new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Circle({
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: [245, 121, 0, 0.8] }),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: [0,0,0,1] }),
                radius: 7
            }),
            text: new ol.style.Text({
                font: '24px Verdana',
                text: this.get('name'),
                offsetY: 20,
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: [255, 255, 255, 0.8]
                })
            })
        })
    ];
};

select.on('select', function(evt){
    var selected = evt.selected;
    var deselected = evt.deselected;

    selected.forEach(function(feature){
        feature.setStyle(styleClick);
    });

    deselected.forEach(function(feature){
        feature.setStyle(null);
    });
});
```

Comment: A faster and simpler hack than mine. Nice! Thanks! The real question here is how OL actually approach this? As Alvin pointed out, you can set a style for the selected feature(s) while setting the interaction. That style accesses and alters only the selected/unselected features (=your solution, faster) or all of them (=my solution, slower)? If the second is true, then your solution is faster and worth it to use it over the native OL one. I think you should make a comment in the gitHub and let community know.

Comment: I don't think there is a performance difference but for sure there's less code styling inside `ol.interaction.Select`. It's up to you.

Comment: I guess it's better go with @AlvinLindstam's answer.

Comment: @JonatasWalker Thanks for your time and effort. Nice, clean answers and code